# Is instancing supported in openGL 3.1?

Tags: c++, opengl, opengl-3

So glVertexAttribDivisor seems to be supported in 3.3. My graphics card only has partial support for 3.3 and you need the glVertexAttribDivisor functions for instancing? Is instancing supported some other way, since the glVertexAttribDivisor function does not work on my graphics card?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`glVertexAttribDivisor()` is not a necessity for instancing. It adds the possibility to advance vertex attributes per instance. Without it, all attributes will advance per vertex as usual.

This means that you will get the same vertex attribute values for all instances in your vertex shader. Everything you want to do differently per instance has to key off the built-in `gl_InstanceID` variable.

For example, if you have per-instance values you want to use in your vertex shader, you could store them in a uniform buffer. In the shader, you then define a uniform block that contains an array, and access the per-instance values by indexing this array with `gl_InstanceID`.

Answer (score 3):

Your GL implementation might support the [`ARB_instanced_arrays`](https://www.opengl.org/registry/specs/ARB/instanced_arrays.txt) extension instead.